# Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Tags: c++

This is my script
i have no idea to solve this error
Please help me 
Thank you so much

```
float angle = 15;
float x, y, z;               // for polygon rotate 

void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear screen and depth buffer
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);


    glVertex2f(160.0, 360.0);
    glVertex2f(300.0, 360.0);
    glVertex2f(160.0, 480.0);
    glVertex2f(300.0, 480.0);

    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(580.0, 200.0);
    glVertex2f(640.0, 200.0);
    glVertex2f(580.0, 480.0);
    glVertex2f(640.0, 480.0);

    glRotatef(angle, -1.0f, 0.0, 0.0);

    angle += 15.0f;






    glEnd();




    glutSwapBuffers(); // dounle buffering

}
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {



    }break;

    case WM_DESTROY: {


        PostQuitMessage(0);

    }break;


    default:break;
    }
    return 0;
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize GLUT

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);// Set up some memory buffers for our display


    glutInitWindowSize(640, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 20);
    glutCreateWindow("My GLUT GAME");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    //glutKeyboardFunc();


    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A linker error will be coming from you you build (and link) your code. Are you using Visual Studio? What kind of project have you built?

Comment: A Windows project requires [`WinMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `main`.

Comment: Please do consider accepting an answer, if it solves the problem. If not, please comment underneath each answer stating why they do not work.

Answer (score 31):

I had to make the application as executable project with output type .exe 
Key change was changing Linker -> System -> Sub-system to **Console**

[image]

Answer (score 26):

You've set the project to build as a Windows application, not a command line application. Change `int main()` to:

`int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Or, change your project properties to be a command line application.

Answer (score 9):

As workaround you can add `WinMain` function from which call `main`:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return main(__argc, __argv);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Wow your suggestion totally worked. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 7):

For me following this helped.

Go to `properties->Linker -> System -> Sub-system` and choose "not set" or "Windows"

Comment: It worked for me, but I would like to understand why?