# How can one hide the console window of a Windows program?

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I am using the wxWidget framework. When I set `System/Subsystem: Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` then my program will start but will show both a GUI and a console. This is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G83PR.png

When I change `System/Subsystem: Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` then it show errors:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Gui_AutoPokemon* gui = new Gui_AutoPokemon();
    wxApp::SetInstance(gui);

    mainArgc = argc;
    mainArgv = argv;

    return wxEntry(argc, argv);
}
```

How can I hide the console window?

Comment: [Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function “int __cdecl invoke_main(void)” (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41141602/6752050)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GUI Windows programs use a different entry point function than console. You're right to use `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`, but then you need to change to using `WinMain`:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR cmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    ....
```

Then use the appropriate `wxEntry` overload:

```
return wxEntry(hInstance, NULL, cmdLine, nCmdShow);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest calling [`FreeConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole). It detaches the console from any window. As an example for my application:

[image: example of a program]